# FFmpeg drawtext width

Tags: ffmpeg

It seems that ffmpeg is great for single line scrolling, but I have not been able to find anyone or any examples that set a multi-line based on a width. I have been looking at DrawText instead of subtitle or aas as I'm not really wanting captioning.

I'm assuming there are only a couple options to go about it:

1) Either it supports it out of the box and I'm just missing the wrap syntax?

2) Most people just calculate the width they have and add in the returns?  (I'm not wanting to use a text file, would prefer to just use the text option.)

3) People only ever want to scroll or have short enough text that they don't want multi line so it just isn't capable with ffmpeg?

Has anyone ever set a width or figured out a way to get reliable wrapping?

Comment: Two questions: Since drawtext and subtitle both render text on video, what is the difference you are wanting? Also, do you want line break after x number of characters? Then why scroll- which is continuous ticker tape type?

Comment: I'm using drawtext vs subtitle because I'm not getting the text from srt files, but from just normal text.  I don't have a x number of characters but width.  Similar to if you created a div in css and set the width and the text would autowrap.  I'm not looking to scroll continuously, but show for a bit and then switch to something else.

Comment: What you want to achieve is a "lower thirds" possibly? When you have a fixed width, you can calculate that only so many characters will fit within that width- that's what I meant. The appearing and going away is beautifully handled by srt format. So why would you not want to use it? That is, put your text in srt format? Although it's your choice finally, but I feel it's the easy way to achieve what you want, unless of course your text is generated/meta-created by some other program on the fly or something.

Comment: Having said that, autowrap could work if we can tell that at p point-size n characters occupy z pixel-widths, and at closest space character insert line break. Maybe it is not implemented inside a filter like drawtext.